# NSPredicate Core Data to-many

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

This is the Core Data model. [Image](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/27/h50u.png/)

DiaCD <--->> HoraCD <<---> ActividadCD

In the entity "Activity" is a category called attribute to filter the activities. My question is: **How could I make a query to give me back the days with activities where the category is "X"?**

Try one:

```
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescriptionDia = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"DiaCD" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *requestDia = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSPredicate *predicateDia = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY relDiaHora.relHoraActividad.categoria == %@", categoria];
    [requestDia setEntity:entityDescriptionDia];
    [requestDia setPredicate:predicateDia];

    NSError *errorDia;
    NSArray *arrayDia = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:requestDia error:&errorDia];
    if ([arrayDia count] > 0) {
        for (DiaCD *dia in arrayDia) {
            NSSet *setHora = dia.relDiaHora;
            HoraCD *horaQuery = [setHora anyObject];
            ActividadCD *actividadQuery = horaQuery.relHoraActividad;
            NSLog(@"Act --> %@ y la categoria --> %@ y la categoria --> %@", actividadQuery.titulo, actividadQuery.categoria, categoria);
        }
    }
```

If I do this query does not return good data that does not respect the category, I'm guessing, do not know why :S.

Try 2:

```
NSPredicate *predicateDia = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"relDiaHora.relHoraActividad.categoria == %@", categoria];
```

If I do the same query but only removing the "ANY" fails. Error: "reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'"

Comment: You need a sub query here. I'll try, one sec...

Comment: Actually your predicate *should work*. It returns all DiaCD objects that are related to *any* HoraCD with the given activity category. - The problem might be that `[dia.relDiaHora anyObject]` returns *some* related HoraCD, not necessarily then one with the given category.

Comment: the ANY clause checks against all items though. i.e. if there is at least one that exists with the criteria then it will get returned. However, this is going through an extra step. i.e. it's not saying "any HoraCD with the category blah" it is saying "any HoraCD where the activity.category is blah" I don't think ANY can be used in this case.

Comment: @Fogmeister: ANY *can* be used, because HoraCD --> ActividadCD is a *to-one* relationship. SUBQUERY is only needed if you traverse *nested to-many* relationships.

Comment: @MartinR Sorry but I do not understand I'm new to iOS and core data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your predicate

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY relDiaHora.relHoraActividad.categoria == %@", categoria];
```

returns all days that have any hour with the given activity category. Your problem seems
to be that

```
NSSet *setHora = dia.relDiaHora;
```

returns *all* hours of the fetched day, not only the hours with the given activity category.

Therefore

```
HoraCD *horaQuery = [setHora anyObject];
```

is *any* hour of the fetched day, and need not have the given activity.

If you need the days and matching hours, you should execute a fetch request on the hours
instead:

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDescriptionHour = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"HourCD" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *requestHour = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSPredicate *predicateHour = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"relHoraActividad.categoria == %@", categoria];
[requestHour setEntity:entityDescriptionHour];
[requestHour setPredicate:predicateHour];

NSError *errorHour;
NSArray *arrayHours = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:requestHour error:&errorHour];
if ([arrayHours count] > 0) {
    for (HourCD *hour in arrayHours) {
        DiaCD *dia = hour.relHoraDia;
        ActividadCD *actividad = hour.relHoraActividad;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @MartinR, this consultation and working but had done and believed that there was any way to get me the data directly from the entity DiaCD but if you can not I will not worry so :)

Comment: @TeRRo: `dia.relDiaHora` will always give you *all* hours of the day, that is completely unrelated to the previous fetch request and predicate. - Did you try my code? Please let me know if there are more problems and I will try to help. - Otherwise, if it works, please note that you can "accept" an answer by clicking on the check mark.

Comment: your query if it works but you get an array with all the hours I have days then duplicate and I need to get a array with the days where there activities with the category "X". Example of Array I need to get: Monday {"HoraCD", "HoraCD", "HoraCD"}, Tuesday {"HoraCD"}   and where this filtering HoraCD by the categoria of ActividadCD.

Comment: @TeRRo: I don't think you can do that with a single fetch request. Either you fetch *days* (as you do in your question) and then filter `dia.relDiaHora` for each day, OR you fetch *hours* (as in my answer) and then sort all hours with the same day together. - Another option would be to use the `setPropertiesToGroupBy` option of NSFetchRequest. Or, if you want to display the objects in a table view, use NSFetchedResultsController and the sectionNameKeyPath parameter to group all hours of one day into sections.

Comment: At the end I'll make two queries return one for me and one for the day I return the hours of that day but one last query data structure type could be mounted as an Array I can not do it. What data structure could use?

Answer (score 0):

OK, the first bit was wrong. However, still follow this note about naming.

**A QUICK NOTE**

You should not be calling your attributes "relItem1Item2". This is something that comes from relational databases. CoreData is not a relational database.

You should name them descriptively as to what they point to.

i.e.

relHoraActividad should be called actividad. As it is pointing to the actividad entity and it is a "to-one" relationship.

Also...

relActividadHora should be called horaCDs. It is pointing to the horaCD entity and it is a "to-many" relationship.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i get an error [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(relDiaHora.relHoraActividad, $actividad, $actividad.categoria == %@)", categoria];

Comment: The error is reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "SUBQUERY(relDiaHora.relHoraActividad, $actividad, $actividad.categoria == %@)"'

Comment: Did you add the @count bit?

Comment: Yes and run but, I keep getting the same result can not get them right, ie not return my activities with the category that I pass :S

Comment: I do not get any errors but the result returns me is not correct. Example: This is what I have to return " Actividad --> Presentación Future T. y el dia --> Conferencia
Actividad --> Conferencia NVIDIA y el dia --> Conferencia " and this is what brings me back " Act --> Apertura Inscripciones y la categoria --> Hardware 
Act --> Evaulación de Modding y la categoria --> Hardware " you notice how I changed the category? why?

Answer (score 0):

I think your setup is absurd. Why have complicated relationships to days and hours when you can simply use `NSDate` attributes?

From your image I see that you store other things in these entities that do not seem to have anything to do with hours or days.

To filter by day or time, you typically use a pattern like this

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"time > %@ && time < %@", min, max];
```

Comment: The problem is that it is a mirror of a MySQL database in order to synchronize the two databases, and the database was thought to make the synchronized data in android and then arose the need to do well in iOS. But I understand what you say.